# How to use Jbuilder to save output for later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I want to save json into a database field for later use.  How should I go about that with Jbuilder?

I want to use an item's show template, passing in the object, @item to save the output for that Item into the database for later use.

I got some output with the following code:

```
view_paths = Rails::Application::Configuration.new(Rails.root).paths["app/views"]
av_helper = ActionView::Base.new view_paths
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
@job = Job.find(239)
output = av_helper.render(file: '/api/jobs/show.jbuilder', locals: {:@job => @job})
```

How can I render the saved json directly from the controller?

Add this for the action code in the controller

```
def show
   @job = Job.find(params[:id])    
   render :inline => @job.json_output 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### [render_to_string](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string)
>
> Raw rendering of a template to a string.
>
> It is similar to render, except that it does not set the response_body
>   and it should be guaranteed to always return a string.

Also if you're doing it from a controller there you can just use the controller to render it:

```
class JobsController
  def create
    @job = Job.new(item_params) do |job|
      job.my_json_attribute = render_to_string(:show, locals: { :@job => job})
    end
    if @job.save
      redirect_to @job
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

But this seems like a pretty overcomplicated and flawed way to handle something that can be done with [e-tag caching](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/introduction-to-conditional-http-caching-with-rails) and a reverse proxy or even [low level caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching). Especially since you would have to repeat the logic when updating the item.

Comment: It takes over 30seconds to build the json.  So caching is no use because the first load is too slow.

Comment: Well what can I say. jBuilder is known for being slow as hell and you probably have multiple n+1 queries and other issues if it's taking 30 seconds.

Comment: its an enourmous amount of data.  its not something we can optimise our way out of, hence considering prebuilding it in a background process.

Comment: But if you're sending an enormous amounts of json to the client you still have a huge problem and you need to consider solution such as paging or both the client and your infrastructure will suffer.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't appropriate either.